# How to compute tanh(X) where X is a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, hyperbolic-functions

According to the definition of $\tanh(x)$ on a scalar, we have $\tanh(x) = \frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{e^x + e^{-x}} = \frac{2}{1 + e^{-2x}} - 1$. Now if X is a matrix instead of a scalar, then is it true that $\tanh(X) = (e^X + e^{-X})^{-1}(e^X - e^{-X}) = 2(1 + e^{-2X})^{-1} - 1$?

Thanks!

Comment: $e^X=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}X^n$, where the sum is defined as the sum of matrices and the power is similarly defined.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to ask if the equality above holds for matrices as well.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. If the first equality is the *definition* of $\tanh(X)$, then the second one is straightforward to check.

Comment: Yes, these functional equalities hold when using matrix arguments. And power series that are valid for $|x|<a$ also hold for matrices for which the spectral radius satisfies the same  condition, i.e. $\,\|X\|<a\;$